# Project does not see namespace "ZBar" Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, zbar

I have some problems with binding ZBar Android library in Xamarin.

I follow this tutorial - 
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/

After I  fix all errors, I create test project. In test project I add reference on binding project.

And there is problem - test project does not see namespace of generated binding project.
How to fix this??

Is there any sample with Zbar on Xamarin??

UPDATE:

Resolve this problem. Visual Studio can't correct bind java library. 
Use Xamarin Studio to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve this problem. Visual Studio can't correct bind java library. Use Xamarin Studio to do this.

Comment: You were able to get zbar to work in your Xamarin application by using Xamarin Studio?

Comment: @MikeyB, we moved to zxing library. This library works well.

Comment: For my application ZBar is significantly outperforming ZXing... I needed to switch before I Could get even 50% of my codes recognized.  ZBar gets 99% right for me.

Did you HAVE to switch because Zbar would never work with Xamarin or for other reasons?

Comment: @MikeyB It was long time ago. I can't remember for sure why we moved to zxing library. Binding project build successfully with XS, then we use only dll as reference in VS on windows.